# Python multithreading slow af on neural network activation function

Tags: python, multithreading, neural-network

I am making a neural network WITHOUT the usage of any neural network libraries. Because of this, my code is extremely unoptimized. This is why I decided to use multithreading. However, that seemed to slow down my code by atleast 3 times. Why is multithreading slower in my case, and what optimizations can I do to speed it up.

For the code below: `inputs` are each layer's inputs while `weights` are simply the allocated weights of that layer. `weightedInputs` are 3 dimensional like this : `[[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]]`

Here is my activation function:

```py
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-np.sum(x)))
```

Here is my initial layer function:

```py
def layerSingle(inputs, weights):
    biasedInputs = np.append(np.array(inputs), 1)
    neuronInputs = np.repeat(np.array([biasedInputs]), len(weights), axis = 0)
    weightedInputs = neuronInputs * np.array(weights)
    
    out = list(map(sigmoid, weightedInputs))

    return np.array(out)
```

Here is with multithreading:

```py
def layerMulti(inputs, weights):
    biasedInputs = np.append(np.array(inputs), 1)
    neuronInputs = np.repeat(np.array([biasedInputs]), len(weights), axis = 0)
    weightedInputs = neuronInputs * np.array(weights)

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = executor.map(sigmoid, weightedInputs)
    
    out = np.array([])
    for row in result:
        out = np.append(out, row)

    return np.array(out)
```

Here are the libraries I import:

```py
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures
from copy import deepcopy
```

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: You cannot rely on multithreading to speed up compute-bound code in python because of the Global Interprer Lock. Read up here: https://realpython.com/python-gil/

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. Does this mean that a multiprocessing pool can help?

Comment: You might be able to use multiprocessing, but depending on how you do it there might be significant overhead for creating the processes and then gathering the results. Might be worth a shot.